# Binding NULL arguments with queryWithFactory

Tags: android, sql

I'm writing an Android app that needs to write to the SQLite database. Currently it's using `rawQueryWithString` to build the update query, and I'm using `?` placeholders in my query combined with the `selectionArgs` argument to pass in the actual values.

However, sometimes I actually want to update my column (of type `Date`) to `NULL`, but if I pass in `null` in my `selectionArgs` then I get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
```

I can't really see how I'm supposed to make it work when the value is actually null. I guess I could pass in an empty string, which in the case of a `Date` column like this might just work, but suppose it was a string column and I actually *did* want to mean `NULL` in contrast to the empty string (or are they considered equivalent in SQLite?)

Here's the code:

```
String timestampStr = null; // Obviously not really set like this
SQLiteDatabase d = getWritableDatabase();
DBCursor c = (DBCursor) d.rawQueryWithFactory(
        new DBCursor.Factory(),
        "Update subject set schedulingTimestamp = ? where identifier = ?",
        new String[] { timestampStr, subjId.toString() },
        null);
d.close();
```

The column was added with the following query, so I presume it's a nullable column since I didn't specify otherwise:

```
ALTER TABLE subject ADD schedulingTimestamp DATE;
```

Comment: I'm assuming your columns are NULLable...

Comment: Thanks, added a comment to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not meant to be used for inserting/updating values in SQL, AFAIK. In Android, you can use `ContentValues` instead in conjunction with the `update()` method, instead of trying to shoehorn it in the raw query method.